# How can i make a custom list of files in django?

Tags: python, django, file

I have an app in Django where users upload some files(xlsx), the information gets extracted and the files are stored in /media.
I want a page/view where the users should be able to browse through the files by folder structure or alphabetically and they should be able to download them from the server.

What i have now is as basic as it gets:
this is the .html

```
{% block Content%}
{% if documents %}
    <ul id="files_ul">
        {% for document in documents %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p> No documents. </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have a model named Document and i've added this:

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to urls.py which i know it's not secure.

I don't need something like Filer because i already have that but i didn't yet figure out how to configure.

I only know python and that not extensively and i'm new to Django so any help would be really appreciated.

It would be of great help if you could show me at least how to change the name of the files that appear now in this view,

```
document.docfile.name
```

Results in folder1/folder2/filename and i would want only the filename to appear.

Model

```
class Document(models.Model):

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    upload_user=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='documents')
    upload_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    docfile=models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m')
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing now with these html

Comment: @Exprator i dont know how to change the name of the filename, i edited the question.

Comment: Also, i want to group the files by folder structure inside the documents folder and i don't know how to grab this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model where you have defined filefield put this function

```
def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.docfile.name)
```

and in template

```
 <a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.filename }}</a>
```

Comment: It displays nothing now.

Comment: can you post you model? @Mike

Comment: still same result

Comment: It s exactly what i had in the first place:|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146225/discussion-between-exprator-and-mike).